# Change header buttons fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I am having trouble with the full calendar plugin

I have header buttons for desktop, but if my screen goes to 960px width, I want the header buttons changed from position

Desktop position:

`header: {
    left: 'title',
    center: false,
    right: 'prev, today, next, ',
},`

Changed position:

```
windowResize: function(view) {
  if ($(window).width() <= 960){
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar( {
      header: {
        left: 'title',
        center: 'prev, today, next',
        right: '',
      },
      defaultView: resourceDay,
    } );
  }
},
```

The right variable must have custom buttons through this code:

```
$('.fc-header-right').append('<span class="fc-button fc-button-addEmployee ui-state-default ui-corner-right"><span class="fc-button-inner"><span class="fc-button-content">Afspraak inplannen</span><span class="fc-button-effect"><span></span></span></span></span><span class="dragMeIcon"></span>');
$('.fc-header-right .fc-button-addEmployee').removeClass('ui-corner-right').addClass('addEmployee');
```

For desktop everything works fine, but if I changed the width, the buttons don't change.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: It works [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hLgwt/) if i delete the line `defaultView: resourceDay`. Are you sure that `resourceDay` var contains a valid value for calendar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fullcalendar custom buttons in header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847514/fullcalendar-custom-buttons-in-header)